# addEventListener and memory leak

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

Im doing a small game for college work and I don't understand very well how the garbage collector works
with EventListeners, I feel that the "preCastTimer" EventListener never gets removed on the code below. The problem is that I have no idea how to remove it once its complete.

below is the code Im using to cast a spell when a key is pressed

Here I have the casting functions called by KeyboardEvents, fireball is a MovieClip

```
preCast(fireball);

function preCast(spell)
{
    var tempSpell:Object = new spell;//create an object for the spell so castTime is accessible. 
    var preCastTimer:Timer = new Timer(tempSpell.castTime,1);
    var spellFunc:Function = cast(spell);
    preCastTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, spellFunc);

    preCastTimer.start();
}

function cast(spell):Function {
    return function(e:TimerEvent):void {
        parent.addChild(new spell);//For some reason if spell is not created here it never gets a parent
  };
}
```

Here is the code for the fireball MovieClip:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class fireball extends MovieClip {
        public var castTime:uint = 1000;


        public function fireball() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }

}
```

The code below is in the fireball timeline. I understand it's better to use class, but I still don't understand parenting when the code is in the package and not on the timeline frame

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

if (parent)//only run if a parent exists, when created as object no parent is defined
{
    x = parent.getChildByName("player").x;
    y = parent.getChildByName("player").y;

    var direction = new Point(parent.mouseX - x,parent.mouseY - y);
    rotation = Math.atan2(parent.mouseY - y,parent.mouseX - x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    direction.normalize(5);
    if (direction.x == 0 && direction.y == 0)
    {
        parent.removeChild(this);
        return;
    }

    var spellTimer:Timer = new Timer(500,1);


    spellTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, spellKiller);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, motion);

    spellTimer.start();
}

function spellKiller(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, motion);
    spellTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, spellKiller);
    parent.removeChild(this);
}

function motion(e:Event)
{
    x +=  direction.x * 5;
    y +=  direction.y * 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `addEventListener` has the `useWeakReference` argument (5th argument).

```
public function addEventListener(
    type:String,
    listener:Function,
    useCapture:Boolean = false,
    priority:int = 0,
    useWeakReference:Boolean = false
):void;
```

From the `EventDispatcher` [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29):

> If you no longer need an event listener, remove it by calling
>   removeEventListener(), or memory problems could result. Event
>   listeners are not automatically removed from memory because the
>   garbage collector does not remove the listener as long as the
>   dispatching object exists (unless the useWeakReference parameter is
>   set to true).

The solution would be to simply convert your `addEventListener` calls to use weak references, where appropriate.

```
foo.addEventListener(type, listener, false, 0, true);
```

Please let me know if you're not sure how this helps you.

Comment: Use weak reference is a bad practice. You should *always* clean up your code when possible.

Comment: **When possible**, sure. Weak references do have their uses in preventing cyclic references from creating memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

So your code is a bit overly complicated with some important parts missing so I cannot really comment on that parent thing. As far as I understand the timer should fire once and then you want its listener removed, correct? Well, that's pretty easy to achieve:

```
function cast(spell):Function {
    return function(e:TimerEvent):void {
        parent.addChild(new spell);
        e.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, spellFunc);
  };
}
```

Why do you have the feeling that this is not the correct solution? You can test that the listener is removed by simply changing the TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE to TimerEvent.TIMER (and removing the repeat count passed to the constructor of your timer). It should add the spell once and no more.

Also note that the garbage collector will not pick it up right away (well, very probably not!). It may pick it up somewhere in the future or never. Actually, the timer will probably never get picked if you don't set it to null or you don't create another timer object and assign it to the same variable as your reference will remain and therefore it will never get eligible for garbage collection.